# Help with S&P probability

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

1. According to this model, what is the probability that the change in the S&P $500$ on a particular day is positive. We have $P(X>0)$ and then converting to standard normal table I get $P(Z>(0-0.75)/25=0.03$ because $\mu=0.75$ and the SD is $25$. Then using standard normal table we get $0.512$
2. What is the third quartile quartile of daily changes in the S&P $500$? I know that $\mu$ and SD is the same, but would I just use $0.75$ as $X$? that would not make any sense because then you would just be dividing $0/25$? Also is there a way to do 1. without the standard table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me address your last question first: "Also is there a way to do (a) without the standard table?"

Well, one needs to know enough about the density of $X$ to determine the probability $\mathbb{P}(X > 0)$.  Where we get this information, is secondary.  A table is a convenient device for getting an approximation close enough.  Another way is to compute the appropriate integral of the density function, a task no less pleasant than looking into the table.

The third quartile of $X$ is such a value $q$ that $\mathbb{P}(X \leq q) \geq 0.75$.  Your normalized variable is
$$
Z = (X - \mu) / \mbox{SD},
$$
so the condition $X \leq q$, rewritten in terms of $Z$, would be
$$
Z \leq (q - \mu)/\mbox{SD}.
$$
Thus, you would be using the table to find the $q' = (q - \mu)/\mbox{SD}$ such that
$$
\mathbb{P}(Z \leq q') \geq 0.75.
$$
Once you've found the $q'$, solve for $q$.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I am still confused what you are pointing to. .75 being q? I know mu is .75 and the SD is 25.

Comment: The $0.75$ I am pointing to has nothing to do with the mean or standard deviation.  It is related to the condition of being in the third quartile.  Interpret it as the probability that is no lower than $75\%$.

BTW, the $q$ is *not* the $75\%$.  The $q$ is the threshold value that $X$ does not exceed with probability at least $75\%$.

To "unconfuse", try changing question 2 to "What is the 8-th decile of daily changes in the S&P 500?"

Answer (score 0):

**Comment.** Graph of $\mathsf{NORM}(\mu = 0.75, \sigma=25)$ showing 75th percentile $17.61224.$ (See initial comment moved just below from elsewhere on this page.)

```
1 - pnorm(0, .75, 25)
[1] 0.5119665    # area to right of vertical green line

qnorm(.75, .75, 25)
[1] 17.61224     # 75% of area is left of vertical red
```

May be confusing to see two `.75`s. Suppose you wanted the median (50th percentile). Should get mean $\mu = .75.$

```
qnorm(.5, .75, 23)
[1] 0.75
```

[image]

```
curve(dnorm(x,.75, 25), -75, 75, ylab="PDF", col="blue", lwd=2,
      main="NORM(0.75, 25")
 abline(v=17.61, col="red", lty="dotted", lwd=2)
 abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0, col="green2")
```

Comment: For $\mathsf{Norm}(μ=0.75,σ=26).$ In R, `pnorm` is a normal CDF and `qnorm` is the quantile function (inverse CDF). It is not necessary to standardize because the R procedures accept parameters μ,σ. In R, code `1 - pnorm(0, .75, 25)` returns $0.5119665,$ and `qnorm(.75, .75, 25)` returns $17.61224.$ In the latter, the first $.75$ is for the 75th quantile (upper quartile), the second is for $μ=0.75.$